# How display Multiplication Table in columns in java. No use extra java funcions, just loops and conditionals

Tags: java, loops, conditional-statements

I would like to display the values in three columns and three rows. This is my code:

```
public class MultiplicationTable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        for(int i=2;i<=10;i++){
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println(" The table " + i);
          for(int j=2;j<=10;j++) {
              System.out.println(" " +i + " x " + j + " = " + i*j + "\t");
          }
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't include "THANK SO MUCH." in your question. It is useless noise.

Comment: Also, what have you tried? What is the problem? How in the world can we help if you don't tell us what you want to do and why it won't work?

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: The usual format for the multiplication table is an n x n table representing the product of all pairs integers between 1 and n (inclusive). Is that what you want?

Comment: My code displays the values only ​​in one column, and I want it in three columns and three rows

Comment: I'm trying this, but it doesn't work <code>  for(int i=2;i<=10;i++){
   System.out.println();
   System.out.println(" The table " + i);
    for(int j=2;j<=10;j++) {
     System.out.print(" " +i + " x " + j + " = " + i*j + "\t");
     if (j%3==0){
      System.out.println(" "); 
     }else{
      System.out.print(" "); 
     }
    }
    } </code>

Answer (score 0):

(Corrected) Stupid of me; just ordinary tables but in 3 columns.

Instead of "x" you may write "\u00d7" or "×" which is the real math operator ×.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final String TAB = "    ";
    for(int y = 0; y < 3; y++) {
        for(int j = 2; j <= 10; j++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < 3; x++) {
                int i = 2 + y*3 + x;
                System.out.printf("The table %2d  " + TAB, i);
                System.out.printf("%2d x %2d = %3d" + TAB, i, j, i*j);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: I corrected; had twice y++ instead of the second time x++. Copy error.

Comment: I want something like this: ![Multiplication Table](http://www.flickr.com/photos/93547841@N04/8504921847/in/photostream/)

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i=2;i<=10;i++){
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println(" The table " + i);
    for(int j=2;j<=10;j++) {
        System.out.println( i + " x " + j + " = " + i*j );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String temp     = "";
String lbl      = "TABLE #";

int num         = 10,
    rowLength   = 10,
    colLength   = 3;

int tableNumber = 1, 
    counter     = colLength,
    index       = 1;


for ( int colLabel = index; colLabel <=num; colLabel++, tableNumber++ ){                        
    System.out.printf("%11s %-10s",lbl + tableNumber, "");

    if ( colLabel == counter || colLabel == num ){
        System.out.println();
        for ( int row = 1; row <=rowLength; row++){
            for ( int column = index; column <=colLabel; column++){
                temp    = String.format("%4d x %-3d= ", column, row );
                temp   += String.format("%-10d",(column * row));
                System.out.printf("%20s",temp);
            }   
            System.out.println();
        //  temp = "";
        }

        System.out.println("\n");
        index    = (tableNumber + 1);                               
        counter += colLength;   
    }                               
}
```